# I want to know an estimate of $a_{i, j}$

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Let
$$
  a_{ij} 
= \begin{cases}
  -1,  & \text{if $i = -1$ and $j = -1$} \\
  1, & \text{if $i = -1$ and $j \ne -1$}  \\
  1, & \text{if $i \ne -1$ and $j = -1$}  \\
  a_{i-1, j-1} + a_{i-1, j} + 1, & \text{if $i \ne -1$ and $j \ne -1$}.  \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $a_{i, j}$ is defined for the integers $i \ge -1$ and $j \ge -1$ as above.

I want to know a good lower bound and a good upper bound of $a_{i, j}$.

I want to know the answer of a problem from the following site: 
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/

The problem is:

Estimate the number of recursive calls that would be used by the following code 
to compute binomial$(100, 50, 0.25)$. I know that $a_{100, 50}$ is the exact number of the recursive calls.

```
public static double binomial(int N, int k, double p) {

if (N == 0 && k == 0) return 1.0; 

if (N < 0 || k < 0) return 0.0; 

return (1.0 - p) *binomial(N-1, k, p) + p*binomial(N-1, k-1, p); 

}
```

Here is my estimate:

$2^0 + 2^1 + \dots + 2^{51} = 2^{52} - 1 <$ the number of recursive calls $< 2^0 + 2^1 + \dots + 2^{101} = 2^{102} - 1$.

I'm sorry for my poor English.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [C++ program](http://ideone.com/YRCfKQ) and got the following result

$$a(2i+1,i) = \{3, 15, 63, 255, 1023\}=4^{i+1}-1,i:=0..4; $$

That was the first dependency I've noted after $a(i,i) = 2^{i+2}-3$.

So, I think that

$$a(101,50)=4^{51}-1=2^{102}-1$$

Consider $a(i,j) < a(i+1,j)$ $=>$ $a(100,50) < 2^{102}-1$

I think you can estimate lower bound using the fact $a(i,j) < a(i+1,j+1)$ and same formula.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I checked your result is true for $i = 0 \dots 49$:

$$a(2i+1,i) = \{3, 15, 63, 255, 1023, \dots 1267650600228229401496703205375\}=4^{i+1}-1,i:=0..49; $$

I can prove $a(i,i) = 2^{i+2}-3 $ for $i \ge -1$ by induction, but I cannot prove $a(2i+1,i) = 4^{i+1}-1$.

Thanks to your answer, I got the following better estimate:

$$4^i - 1 = a(2i-1, i-1) < a(2i-1, i) < a(2i, i) < a(2i+1, i) = 4^{i+1}-1$$

$$4^{50} - 1 = a(99, 49) < a(99, 50) < a(100, 50) < a(101, 50) = 4^{51}-1$$

Comment: Mb it's enough?) The formula is recursive, values increases with i,j, you have a dependence, do you really need to prove it?) I'm always trying to find sequencies on oeis.org to simplify calculations without spending time to understand everything. So, as for me, this problem is solved)

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing, the recursive algorithm is really inefficient for this kind of problem.

Second thing, to bound $a_{ij}$ :

- If $j>i$, then $a_{i,j} = a_{i,i+1}$

Recursively, $a_{i,i+1} = 2^{i+2}-1$

- If $j\leq i$, then $a_{i,j} \leq a_{i,i+1}$

And recursively, $a_{i,j} \geq 2\binom{i+2}{j+1}-1$

Comment: Thank you very much.

From your answer,

If $j \gt i$, then $a_{i,j} = 2^{i+2}-1$.

If $j \le i$, then $a_{i,j} \le a_{i,i} = 2^{i+2}-3$.

$a_{i,j} \geq 2\binom{i+2}{j+1}-1$ is not true.

$1 = a_{0,0} \lt 2\binom{0+2}{0+1}-1 = 4-1 = 3$.